# Does green tea keep it's weight-loss benefits after multiple brewing?

Tags: weight-loss

Just as in the title,
I am wondering if I can brew the same leaves multiple times
when I'm using green tea as a weight loss helper.
I like quality tea but it also costs much and dumping
the leaves after just one cup feels a little bit wasteful,
but still, I'm also after the weight-loss benefits and
I'm not sure if they are kept after brewing tea around 4 times.

Comment: Hi Karol, and welcome to the Fitness SE! Unfortunately, since your question doesn't relate to exercise, and is a nutrition-only question, it's off-topic here. Please have a look at the Help Center to see what would generally be on-topic.

Comment: @Alec: He is a brand new user with 1 reputation. Can you help suggest which Stack Exchange he can ask this on rather than just directing him to the Help Center?